# How to change the axes labels on a boxplot

Tags: matlab

When using the `boxplot` command from Statistics toolbox, the axes properties change in a strange way. For example, one gets

```
 
    XTick = []
    XTickLabel = 
    XTickLabelMode = manual
    XTickMode = manual
```

What is happening to the axes and how one can rename the labels, and/or drop some of the ticks?

Comment: What data are you calling `boxplot` with?

Comment: It is difficult to describe the data. Let's say it has many groups. The change in the behavior of the axes seems to occur after a call to `boxplot` regardless of what the data is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `boxplot` using the optional `labels` parameter.

---

**Edit** - further information about what `boxplot` actually does.

`boxplot` does some complicated stuff - type `edit boxplot` to take a look through the code, and you'll see it's a very long and intricate function. Basically it makes a blank axis with no axis labels, which is why you're seeing empty values for `XTick` etc. Then it makes the boxplot elements out of individual lines, and it simulates fake axis labels by adding text elements. You can find them and modify them directly by plotting into a figure `f`, then getting the `Children` of `f`, then iterating through to get their `Children`. Eventually you'll find text elements with the label names.

Comment: Thanks, this takes care of my problem, which was  rotating the labels to be vertical (by setting `labelorientation` property to `inline`.) Still, it does not explain what `boxplot` does to the axes.

Comment: `boxplot` does some complicated stuff - type `edit boxplot` to take a look through the code, and you'll see it's a very long and intricate function. Basically it makes a blank axis with no axis labels, which is why you're seeing empty values for `XTick` etc. Then it makes the boxplot elements out of individual lines, and it simulates fake axis labels by adding `text` elements. You can find them and modify them directly by plotting into a figure `f`, then getting the `Children` of `f`, then iterating through to get their `Children`. Eventually you'll find `text` elements with the label names.

Comment: @SamRoberts What a great comment - this should be part of your answer.

Comment: Holy crap, 4k lines! I wrote my own version long ago before I had the statistics toolbox, and it's only 91 lines.

Comment: @passerby51 I've seen your question (or very similar) 2 or 3 times on StackOverflow previously - in order to help others find this answer more easily, could you mark it as accepted if you feel it's given you a solution?

Comment: @Sam Roberts, thanks for the comments. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
xtix = {'A','B','C'};   % Your labels
xtixloc = [1 2 3];      % Your label locations

set(gca,'XTickMode','auto','XTickLabel',xtix,'XTick',xtixloc);
```

For some reasons resetting XTickMode to auto seemed to be key.

Comment: Thank you! Whatever their motivation was for hacking the labels the way they did in `boxplot`, The natural way of dealing with axis labels seems to make way more sense from my perspective. I was shocked to see close to 4000 lines of code in the function. And breaking labels (and my work flow that depends on it) is apparently one of the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Sam Roberts, that was helpful.

I wrote the following to remove group labels based on this advice.  However, it removes ALL the labels, including axis and data tips.  There doesn't seem to be a way to remove a label on an axis but leave it on a data tip.

```
m = get(get(get(figH,'Children'),'Children'),'Children');
for ii = 1:numel(m)
    if(strcmp(get(m(ii),'Type'),'text'))
        set(m(ii),'String', '');
    end
end
```

The variable figH is the handle to your figure.  You can also try gcf if the boxplot is the active figure handle.

Comment: If it doesn't really solve the problem, and you have your own problems, then it should be posted as a new question.